# Smooth Scrolling on Google Maps SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

So I want to limit the Google Maps scrollable area to a certain rectangle on the map based off of the latitude and Longitude values. In order to do this I've written the following code:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
    startLat = 43.331635f;
    startLong = -74.472913f;
    endLat = 43.329106f;
    endLong = -74.470589f;
    float cameraPosLat = (startLat + endLat) / 2.0f;
    float cameraPosLong = (startLong + endLong) / 2.0f;

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:cameraPosLat
                                                        longitude:cameraPosLong
                                                             zoom:18];
    mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeSatellite;
    mapView.delegate = self;
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    [mapView setMinZoom:18 maxZoom:mapView.maxZoom];
    self.view = mapView;
    marker.map = mapView;
}

-(void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)delegateMapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position{
    if(delegateMapView.camera.target.latitude > startLat){
        [delegateMapView moveCamera:[GMSCameraUpdate setTarget:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(startLat, delegateMapView.camera.target.longitude)]];
    }
    if(delegateMapView.camera.target.latitude < endLat){
        [delegateMapView moveCamera:[GMSCameraUpdate setTarget:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(endLat, delegateMapView.camera.target.longitude)]];
    }
    if(delegateMapView.camera.target.longitude < startLong){
        [delegateMapView moveCamera:[GMSCameraUpdate setTarget:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(delegateMapView.camera.target.latitude, startLong)]];
    }
    if(delegateMapView.camera.target.longitude > endLong){
        [delegateMapView moveCamera:[GMSCameraUpdate setTarget:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(delegateMapView.camera.target.latitude, endLong)]];
    }
}
```

And this works well, it stops the map on the points that I want it to stop at, however one thing I have noticed is that on the edges of the acceptable bounds the scrolling is very jumpy, rather than smooth. I was wondering if there was any way to make sure that the map stayed within the bounds specified, while also maintaining smooth scrolling on the edges.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
-(void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)delegateMapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position{
    if(delegateMapView.camera.target.latitude > startLat){
        [delegateMapView animateToCameraPosition:[GMSCameraPosition 
           cameraWithLatitude:startLat 
           longitude:delegateMapView.camera.target.longitude
           zoom:delegateMapView.camera.zoom]];
    }
    if(delegateMapView.camera.target.latitude < endLat){
        [delegateMapView animateToCameraPosition:[GMSCameraPosition 
           cameraWithLatitude:endLat 
           longitude:delegateMapView.camera.target.longitude
           zoom:delegateMapView.camera.zoom]];
    }
    if(delegateMapView.camera.target.longitude < startLong){
        [delegateMapView animateToCameraPosition:[GMSCameraPosition 
           cameraWithLatitude:delegateMapView.camera.target.latitude 
           longitude:startLong
           zoom:delegateMapView.camera.zoom]];
    }
    if(delegateMapView.camera.target.longitude > endLong){
        [delegateMapView animateToCameraPosition:[GMSCameraPosition 
           cameraWithLatitude:delegateMapView.camera.target.latitude 
           longitude:endLong
           zoom:delegateMapView.camera.zoom]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Accordingly with [API docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#moveCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate))

```
-[GMSMapView moveCamera:]
```

> Repositions the camera according to the instructions defined in the update. The move is instantaneous, and a subsequent getCameraPosition() will reflect the new position. See CameraUpdateFactory for a set of updates.

So if you want animation you need to use

```
-[GMSMapView animateCamera:]
```

Be aware that your delegate will be called multiple times during animation.

Answer (score 0):

float imprecision might be part of your issue causing your delegates to be called multiple times.
I would use NSNumber for storing your min/max and performing lower/greater checks.
I would use a flag for the delegate not to execute twice.

Something along these lines:

```
NSNumber *lat = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:delegateMapView.camera.target.latitude];
if(lat > self.startLat && !self.hasChangedCameraLat){
    [delegateMapView animateToCameraPosition:[GMSCameraPosition 
        cameraWithLatitude:[self.startLat doubleValue] 
        longitude:delegateMapView.camera.target.longitude
        zoom:delegateMapView.camera.zoom]];
    self.hasChangedCameraLat = YES;
}
else {
    self.hasChangedCameraLat = NO;
}
```